# Contiguous elements with different size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a menu and a table that is contiguous to that menu, the table header is taking the size of the menu:

[image]

I want to set the size of the table independently of the size of the menu, I want it to appear to the right, and to be responsive, so if I resize the window or change resolution it keep looking good.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What did you try ? Can you share your code on JSFiddle ?

Comment: Yes. Without showing what you have now, it's impossible to tell you what you need to change.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I'm using a lot of CSS, so it was hard to create a fiddle to reproduce the problem. I was able to solve this using style="float: left;", now the grid appears next to the menu correctly.